# looping through column while merging pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes r_df and s_df. In s_df the columns are named 'C1 and 'p'. I would like to merge r_df and s_df if values in 'p' satisfy some condition. Example

pd.merge(s_df.loc[s_df['p'] <= 0.2],r_df,on = "C1")

I would like to do this for a range say s_df['p'] in the range between 0 and 1. I am not sure how to set up a loop in the merge statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
pd.merge(s_df.loc[s_df['p'].between(0,1)],r_df,on = "C1")
```